# Is this a correct way to show convergence for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k (arctan(\frac{1}{k}))^2$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

Is this a correct way to show convergence for $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k (arctan(\frac{1}{k}))^2$?

Ratio test with $lim_{k->\infty} |\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}|: \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac {\frac{(\frac{1}{k+1})^{2n+1}}{2n+1}}{\frac{(\frac{1}{k})^{2n+1}}{2n+1}})^2=...=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-\frac{1}{k+1})^{4n+2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}((1-\frac{1}{k+1})^n)^4(1-\frac{1}{k+1})^2$

According to the binomial theorem we have: $\lim_{n->\infty} \lim_{k->\infty}(1-\frac{1}{k+1})^n=\lim_{n->\infty} \lim_{k->\infty} 1-\frac{1}{k+1}+(-\frac{1}{k+1})^2)+...+(-\frac{1}{k+1})^n=\\lim_{n->\infty} 1+0+0^2+...+0^n=1$

So $R=1$ which means that it converges for $|x|<1$.
For $x=1$ we have exactly $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (arctan(\frac{1}{k}))^2$, which converges $\implies$ convergence for $x=-1$ also. So convergence $\forall x: |x|\leq 1$.

Comment: You are taking the limit of the absolute value of the ratio of two terms.  Why is there a sigma to the right of the equal sign?

Comment: @EricTowers Which one are yo referring to?

Comment: Do you see more than one limit of an absolute value of a ratio of terms that is followed by an equals sign that is followed by capital sigmas?

Comment: @EricTowers I see what you mean now. The sigma is from the Taylor expansion of arctan.

Comment: Then why is the $x$ missing?

Comment: Hmm, I might be completely lost, but I thought $x=\frac {1}{k}$.

Comment: So a sum with arctan is essentialy a double summation?

Comment: $x^k$ is in your summand.  The argument to arctangent is $1/k$, so there should be no $x$s in the arctangents or any expansions related to them.

Comment: It depends on your definition of arctangent.  If arctangent is "the inverse of the tangent function (restricted to $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$)", then arctangent is not automatically a sum.  There are sums and integrals that also give the arctangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up your limit, then apply L'Hopital's rule.
\begin{align*}
\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k} \right| 
    &= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{x^{k+1} \arctan^2 \left( \frac{1}{k+1} \right)}{x^{k} \arctan^2 \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)} \right|  \\
    &= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left|x  \frac{ \arctan^2 \left( \frac{1}{k+1} \right)}{ \arctan^2 \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)} \right|  \\
    &= \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} |x|  \frac{ \arctan^2 \left( \frac{1}{k+1} \right)}{ \arctan^2 \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)}  &  &  \text{squares are automatically nonnegative}  \\
    &= |x| \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \arctan^2 \left( \frac{1}{k+1} \right)}{ \arctan^2 \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)}  \\
    &\overset{L'H}= |x| \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \frac{ \frac{1}{1 + \left( \frac{1}{k+1} \right)^2 }}{ \frac{1}{1 + \left( \frac{1}{k} \right)^2 }}  \\
    &= |x| \cdot 1  \\
    &= |x|  \text{.}
\end{align*}
Now the ratio test gives you a condition on the value of this limit to ensure convergence: $|x| < 1$.

Now to the endpoints.  Suppose $x = 1$.  Then we consider $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \arctan^2 \frac{1}{k}$.  One way to proceed is to note $\arctan x < x$ for $x > 0$.  So
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \arctan^2 \frac{1}{k} < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}  \text{,}  $$
which is a convergent series.

Now suppose $x = -1$.  From the previous, we know the sum we obtain is absolutely convergent, hence convergent.  Therefore, the sum converges for $x \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: In the book we use, $x^k$ is not used when doing ratio/root test, but I see what you mean now.

Comment: @Labbsserts: Your summands contain $x$s, so the ratio test for this sum contains $x$s.

Comment: Were there any other errors in the "proof"?

Comment: I stopped after the first "What the !!!"  You replaced a ratio of arctangents with a single sum, but put the summands of one series as numerators and the summands of the other series as denominators.  This is as wrong as claiming $\frac{a+b}{c+d} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{b}{d}$.  I didn't read further.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification.